# Is there a way to resolve this "npm install" issue?

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs2, npm-install

I have a Vue 2 project running on a windows 10 system. My Node version is `v16.13.0` and npm is `8.5.0`. I got some errors when I tried serving the app, so I deleted the `node_modules` folder and tried to reinstall the packages. However, I keep on getting this instead.

```
npm WARN deprecated loadash@1.0.0: Package is unsupport. Please use the lodash package instead.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@2.2.1: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0: 3.x is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
[##################] | reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/core-js Completed in 142899ms
```

This process gets stuck at the above line after which you get the following errors:

```
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@2.2.1: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0: 3.x is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\9d\0c\a9d28d7f98d75b4ced4f3ba9079304ab9a0674313fe3082a4d8b06d48c6a11378765061a89b6842e0a710e2b3813570834656882a10cba4b131e6d0561f0
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, lstat 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\9d\0c\a9d28d7f98d75b4ced4f3ba9079304ab9a0674313fe3082a4d8b06d48c6a11378765061a89b6842e0a710e2b3813570834656882a10cba4b131e6d0561f0'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-16T09_14_55_692Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: What error is there at `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-16T09_14_55_692Z-debug-0.log`

Comment: remove the cache C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache  and rerun. if this still happens use yarn to check if this error is also happening there

Comment: @MennoSpijker the logs are numerous.

Comment: Did you try `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`? :o

Comment: I just ended up reinstalling node

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue when run `npm i` or `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` or `npm i --force`. I found this article is quite usefull : https://sebhastian.com/npm-warn-deprecated/ by running `npm install --loglevel=error` and solved my problem

Comment: You're just logging errors and ignoring all warnings!